# how get results from django rest api?

Tags: java, android

how get results from django rest api?

```
https://pastebin.com/nsA3xRtr

https://pastebin.com/QWTGaYAF

https://pastebin.com/hDwCBPd7
```

It's work if I disabled Pagination

this api

```
https://igbaria.pythonanywhere.com/api/test/city/
```

Comment: this my error



`Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $`

Comment: your JSON response is an object but you try to convert it to list.

Comment: How i can do it?

Comment: check the answer

Comment: @HassanMohamad If it worked for you.. mark some answer as correct answer. It will help others to solve same kind of problem

Answer (score 0):

you should create a class as below to pars this JSON

```
public class Response{


    @SerializedName("next")
    String next;
    @SerializedName("previous")
    String previous;
    @SerializedName("count")
    int count;
    @SerializedName("count")
    int count;

    @SerializedName("results")
    ArrayList<City> results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error occurs because you map json to java class incorrectly. Use this ones:

```
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class CityListItemResponse {

    @SerializedName("count")
    public Integer count;
    @SerializedName("next")
    public String next;
    @SerializedName("previous")
    public Object previous;
    @SerializedName("results")
    public List<City> results = null;
}


import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class City {

    @SerializedName("id")
    public Integer id;
    @SerializedName("title")
    public String title;
}
```

For creating data classes correctly I advise U to use this instrument
[link](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Just select your options paste JSON and look at preview

Comment: Thanks to all
@SerializedName required ?

Comment: @HassanMohamad if field name in java and json is different `@SerializedName` required, if same it will work without this annotation

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.